# Javascript floodfill question error with stack size

Tags: javascript, flood-fill

I am trying to implement foodfill algo with no use :( can you help me.

Here is my core with error that I get. How can I solve it?

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.js"></script>
<script>
function setup() {
  createCanvas(800,600);
  noLoop();

}

function mojfloodfill(x,y)
{
    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if (pixelData[3] == 0)
    {
        set(x, y, color(200,0,200));
        mojfloodfill(x+1,y);
        mojfloodfill(x-1,y);
        mojfloodfill(x,y+1);
        mojfloodfill(x,y-1);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

function draw() {

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();


    updatePixels();

    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(20, 20, 1, 1).data;
    textFont("courier", 24); 
    text(pixelData,20,20);
    console.log(pixelData);

    var r = pixelData[0];
    var g = pixelData[1];
    var b = pixelData[2];
    var a = pixelData[3];
    console.log('Czerwony: '+r);
    console.log('Niebieski: '+b);
    console.log('Zielony: '+g);
    console.log('Przezroczystosc: '+a);

    mojfloodfill(70,70);
    updatePixels();

}
</script>
```

eroor

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at p5.Renderer2D.p5.Color._parseInputs (VM50 p5.js:6878)
    at new p5.Color (VM50 p5.js:6491)
    at p5.color (VM50 p5.js:6174)
    at mojfloodfill (:13:16)
    at mojfloodfill (:14:9)
    at mojfloodfill (:15:9)
    at mojfloodfill (:14:9)
    at mojfloodfill (:15:9)
    at mojfloodfill (:14:9)
    at mojfloodfill (:15:9)

Comment: Perhaps you `console.log(pixelData[3])` to see it is always 0?

Comment: I checked it, it changes from time to time so I guess it is correct.